# Find the solutions of an equation in mod 8

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> find all solutions to each of the following equations:
>
> (a) $3x = 2$ mod 8
>
> (b) $4x = 4$ mod 8
>
> (c) $4x^2 = 4$ mod 8
>
> (d) $4x + 4x^2 = 0$ mod 8

Those are my answers:

a) $x=6$

b) $x=1 , x=3 , x=5, x=7$

c) $x=1 , x=3 , x=5, x=7$

d) $x=0, x=1 , x=2,  x=3 , x=4, x=5, x=6, x=7$

P.S: All my answers are in mod 8

Are my answers all correct?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Your answers are all correct

Comment: The answer to (a) should be $x\equiv 6\pmod8$ etc.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, I forgot to mention that all my answers are in mod 8

Comment: Yes they are...

Comment: d) is true for any integer because $2\mid x(x+1)$ so $8\mid 4x(x+1)$.

Comment: This is exact, but lacks of any justification.